# For Loop not looping through all the data

Tags: python, selenium, loops, if-statement, web-scraping

I'm trying to loop through some text which I got from a website but the if statements in the loop are not skipping what I don't need and on the other side, the text that I need, is not being looped through and printed.

```
for i in range(14):
  posting = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"slider_container")][1]')

for value in posting:
 values= (value.text)

#cleaning text
number= range(31)
text=[]

for i in values.split():

  if i == 'new':
   continue
  if i == 'Today·More...':
   continue
  if i == 'Easily apply':
   continue
  if i == 'Just posted·More...':
   continue
  if i == 'Just posted':
   continue
  if i == 'Responsive employer':
   continue

  for m in number:
   date = str(m) + 'days ago·More...'
   if i == date:
     continue

  for m in number:
   date = str(m) + 'days ago'
   if i == date:
     continue

  text.append(i)
  print (text)
```

Comment: Could you please mention the expectation from the above code?

Comment: Declare variable 'values' on global level. Here, you are initialized variable inside second for loop. But, initialization and assignment both are happening inside same block i.e values can hold only one value (every iteration values will be reassigned). To overcome this, declare values on global level or outside 2nd for loop as List and try.